# Can't upload files with CodeIgniter 2.1.0

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, codeigniter-2

I'm having problems uploading files with CodeIgniter 2.1.0, as I recieve the $_FILES array empty.

This is the form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?= base_url()?>nicUpload/test" method="POST">
  Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
```

The action in the rendered form takes the value: `http://localhost/nicUpload/test`.

This is the controller:

```
<?php
  class NicUpload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    }
    function test() {
      echo count($_FILES);
    }
  }
?>
```

The result is `0`, I would expect `1`.

I tried doing the same without CodeIgniter:

index.php:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
      Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
      <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php
  echo count($_FILES);
?>
```

and I get the expected result (`1`). So it's not a php configuration problem.

** UPDATE **

I should have said it earlier, but if I use CodeIgniter's Upload class it fails in this lines of CI's `system/libraries/Upload.php`:

```
// Is $_FILES[$field] set? If not, no reason to continue.
if ( ! isset($_FILES[$field]))
{
  $this->set_error('upload_no_file_selected');
  return FALSE;
}
```

as `$_FILES` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Sena I found the problem. I was using the method described [here](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/CodeIgniter_2.1_internationalization_i18n) to use i18n, so when I was uploading to `http://localhost/nicUpload/test` I was being redirected to `http://localhost/spa/nicUpload/test`, in that redirections the information in `$_FILES` was getting lost. So I just had to add `nicUpload` to the `$special` array in `MY_Lang.php`:

```
private $special = array (
  "admin",
  "auth",
  "nicUpload"
);
```

That fixed it, once `$_FILES` had the proper information I could use the proper method to upload files (the method that Sena mentioned).